# Are there any real-world examples of malamanteau?

Tags: neologisms, portmanteau-words, malapropisms

[image: malamanteau]

I know that Randall (from xkcd) invented this word as a joke, but now I'm wondering. Are there any examples of real words that are "A portmanteau created by incorrectly combining a malapropism with a neologism"?

I can think of some words that are close, but not quite right. For example,"misunderestimate" is simultaneously a neologism, a portmanteau, and a malapropism. However, it is not a malamanteau. Are there any better examples of this?

Comment: *cromulent*? It's a combination of *crompehensible* and the suffix *-ulent* (meaning *full of*). But I guess *-ulent* isn't a neologism.

Comment: "Weak-a-pedia" might qualify, if you consider "weak-a" a malapropism for "wiki."

Comment: Yeah I started a blog about the malamanteaus after he did that site. Picked up a few questionable ones just by setting up google alerts for the word. If you run across more I'll totally add them.

http://malamanteaus.blogspot.com/

Comment: malamanteau = neoloschism yes?  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408850/is-there-a-name-for-the-process-of-patterning-new-words-after-old-ones-in-ways-t

Answer (score 4):

A great subcultural linguistic movement is centered on this very concept:  it's a specific Canadian and P/NW slang associated with tech, mechanics, and tradespeople--its apotheosis is a prolific youtuber known by the moniker AvE.  There's a sensational glossary at:
https://bumblefuckerytoenglish.com/

Consider the self-explanatory, but crisply inventive:
prefamulated

Procrasterbation

Shituation

Stealership

unobtainium

Kanuckistan

Sterling examples all of this inventive and emergent ("emectant?") trope in action!
 A quick visit with a curious mind (a "Quisit"?) is well worth the price of admission (So you don't need "Primission" first!)

Comment: Welcome to the site Dr.. Thanks for the great laugh from a great first post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Malamanteau itself is.

> A malamanteau is a neologism for a portmanteau created by incorrectly combining a neologism and a malapropism. It's itself a portmanteau of malapropism and portmanteau. It's also a malapropism of portmanteau. It's also a neologism coined when the comic was made.

Comment: So can you name the neologism and the malapropism that were combined into a portmanteau?

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple uses of the word "skyeeter" as a username online. This is presumably a portmanteau of "yeet" (a neologism referring to a powerful throw) and "skeeter" (a malapropism of "mosquito"). Malamanteau?
Edit: okay, "skeeter" may not strictly be a malapropism, but it's close! I'll keep looking.

Comment: This _kind of_ fits, but I don't think a username is a word.